# Method continues even though data is still loading from Cloud Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem in my app where I have a method called `signUpButtonTapped`:

```
 @objc func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    if !areFieldsValid()! {
        // some error in textfield
        theScrollView.scrollToTop()
    }else { /* create user */ }
```

As you can see I call the method `areFieldsValid()` which checks all my `textFields` for a couple of things including wether not the username is taken or not:

```
//MARK: Validate Fields
func areFieldsValid() ->Bool? {

    var isValid = true

    // check if username is valid
    checkUsername(field: usernameTextField.text!) { (success) in
        if success == true {
            // username is taken
            print("Username is taken")
            self.setupUsernameTextField()
            self.checkUsernameImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
            self.checkUserNameLabel.text = "Benutzername ist bereits vergeben"
            isValid = false
        }
    }

    return isValid
}
```

The problem I have is that the user gets created even if the username is already taken and `areFieldsValid` should actually return `false` but the program still proceeds... 
I guess it's because the data is still loading while the program proceeds? I have no idea on how to fix this issues so I am grateful for every help!

Comment: `checkUsername` is an asynchronous function, you can see that instead of it returning a boolean, you give it a completion handler that gets passed in the `success` parameter. So, your `areFieldsValid` function needs to be asynchronous as well and take a completion handler. Is that enough info for you to look in the right direction?

Comment: @KevinRenskers thanks for your help! with that and Ivans answer I managed to fix the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to the network is *asynchronous*, that means it could finish anytime in the future. Asynchronous calls simply start running and return immediately, calling a completion block (in your case, with a `success` boolean flag) when they finish.

In this case, your definition of `areFieldsValid()` is not correct, since it's expecting to return the result of an asynchronous call (which returns immediately). Your validating function should have a completion closure to handle stuff, like this:

```
func validateFields(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    checkUsername(field: usernameTextField.text!) { success in
        if success {
            // username is taken
            print("Username is taken")
            self.setupUsernameTextField()
            self.checkUsernameImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
            self.checkUserNameLabel.text = "Benutzername ist bereits vergeben"
            self.isValid = false
        }

        completion(success) // call the completion closure with the success status
    }
}
```

So you would call it like this:

```
@objc func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    validateFields { areValid in
        if areValid {
            self.theScrollView.scrollToTop()
        } else {
            // create user
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer! If I understand it correctly I don't need the variable `isValid` inside `validateFields` anymore right? And what exactly does the `areValid` inside `signUpBUttonTapped()` mean?

Comment: `areValid` would be the same value as `success` (you passed it back on `completion(success)`).

Comment: alright, got that. One more problem I have is that inside `validateFields` I have several more criteria that I check and before your change I just changed `isValid` to false but that doesn't affect my function anymore. How do I fix it ?

Comment: fixed it :) I declared `isValid` oustide the function and checked after I call `validateFields` the status. Thanks for your help :)